# Real sun positions for a given time in unity3d

Tags: c#, shadow

I am developing a components that determines how long hour the surfaces are in shadow throughout the year. For this purpose I need to calculate real sun's position for a given specific time and move the sun to this position. How can I achieve this task in unity3d? There are some codes like in the attaching link that calculates the sun's position for a specific time. Is it usable in unity3d and How can I implement this in unity3d? Thanks for answers [sun position in csharp](http://guideving.blogspot.com.tr/2010/08/sun-position-in-c.html)

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Looks like you want others to code for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because somewhat bizarrely the entire solution, is indeed given, at the link supplied by the OP. The OP need, literally, only copy the code and click "Run".

Comment: I don't want others to code for me. I just both trying to learn c# and unity at the same time. I just want to you experienced people to show me the way

Comment: Sun position depends also to your location in world map, you can use this wolfram alpha api http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/989292